# Map or Copy DataAnnotations to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

In my project I have 2 classes. At first the customer as domain model:

```
 public partial class kunden
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihren Vornamen an.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte einen Vornamen ein der mehr als 2 Zeichen hat.")]
    [Display(Name = "Vorname", Description = "Ihr Vorname")]
    public string kunden_vorname { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihren Nachnamen an.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte einen Nachnamen ein der mehr als 2 Zeichen hat.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nachname", Description = "Ihr Nachname")]
    public string kunden_nachname { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihr Passwort ein.")]
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Bitte wählen Sie ein Passwort mit mindestens 7 Zeichen.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [Display(Name = "Passwort", Description = "Ihr Passwort, Sie können es zur eindeutigen Identifikation ihres Accounts verwenden.")]
    public string kunden_passwort { get; set; }
}
```

The second class is my viewmodel:

```
public partial class KundenViewModel
{
    public string kunden_vorname { get; set; }

    public string kunden_nachname { get; set; }

    public string kunden_passwort { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to map/copy the DataAnnotations? Something like this:

```
Mapper.MapDataAnnotations<KundenViewModel, kunden>();
```

And the mapped class looks so:

```
     public class KundenViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihren Vornamen an.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte einen Vornamen ein der mehr als 2 Zeichen hat.")]
    [Display(Name = "Vorname", Description = "Ihr Vorname")]
    public string kunden_vorname { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihren Nachnamen an.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte einen Nachnamen ein der mehr als 2 Zeichen hat.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nachname", Description = "Ihr Nachname")]
    public string kunden_nachname { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Geben Sie bitte ihr Passwort ein.")]
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Bitte wählen Sie ein Passwort mit mindestens 7 Zeichen.")]
    [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Bitte verwenden Sie weniger als 200 Zeichen.")]
    [Display(Name = "Passwort", Description = "Ihr Passwort, Sie können es zur eindeutigen Identifikation ihres Accounts verwenden.")]
    public string kunden_passwort { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work - AutoMapper copies only values. DataAnnotations need to be defined on each class because they define extra behaviour. The easiest way to reduce code duplication would be to create a class containing  the "Kunden" data and let your viewmodel inherit from it, only adding the extra fields you need.